# LinkedIn Marketing API- Invalid complete multipartUpload request

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to upload a video to the Linkedin API as per [the marketing API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#complete-multi-part-upload). I've done the following so far:

- Registered for a multi part asset upload and received the response containing an array of unique multipart URLs to push the corresponding chunks to
- Fetched the chunks from an Amazon S3 bucket where they live using the Range header
- Successfully uploaded all those chunks via PUT to their corresponding URLs, and stored their ETag and HTTP Status code values.
- Created the finalise POST request body as per the link above using the etags and status codes.

Unfortunately my request fails with:

```
'com.linkedin.vector.utils.logic.LogicLayerInvalidException: Invalid complete multipartUpload request ...(stringified payload)'
```

The only part of the request body I haven't added from the example given is the "metadata" field- there's nothing in the documentation to explain what this is or where it's generated from. I'm assuming that's what is missing. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Code for the request in question is as follows:

```js
    // Loop over chunked download URLs and upload segments of S3 file.
    for(let i = 0, l = uploadDetails.partUploadRequests.length; i < l; i++) {
        const item: PartUploadRequest = uploadDetails.partUploadRequests[i];
        const partialParams: GetObjectRequest = { Bucket: video.dynamoData.mp4Bucket, Key: video.dynamoData.mp4Outputs[0], Range: `bytes=${item.byteRange.firstByte}-${item.byteRange.lastByte}` };
        console.log(`Requesting bytes ${item.byteRange.firstByte}-${item.byteRange.lastByte}`);
        const s3PartialObject = await s3Client.getObject(partialParams).promise();
        const response = await axios.put(item.url, s3PartialObject.Body, {
            headers: {
                ...item.headers
            }
        });

        const { status, headers } = response;
        responses.push({
            headers: {
                ETag: headers.etag
            },
            httpStatusCode: status
        });
    };

    // Send all chunk responses off and confirm video upload
    const finaliseVideoPayload: LinkedinFinaliseVideoPostRequest = {
        completeMultipartUploadRequest: {
            mediaArtifact: registerVideoRequest.value.mediaArtifact,
            partUploadResponses: responses
        }
    };

    console.log(`Fetched all parts, readying finalise request with ${finaliseVideoPayload.completeMultipartUploadRequest.partUploadResponses.length} parts.`);

    const json = await axios.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=completeMultiPartUpload', finaliseVideoPayload, {
        headers: {
            'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + channel.token,
            'Host': 'api.linkedin.com'
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this has been already solved. Just in case if it is not.

There is a field 'metadata' which comes in the registerApi for multipart upload. This comes in the field.

> uploadMechanism["com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MultipartUpload"].metadata

Apparently, this is **required** by the completeMultipart api.

So data will be

```
completeMultipartUploadRequest: {
            mediaArtifact: registerVideoRequest.value.mediaArtifact,
            metadata: registerVideoRequest.value.uploadMechanism["com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MultipartUpload"].metadata,
            partUploadResponses: responses
        }
```

It took me a day to figure out that the field which has no value(empty string) is required. Maybe a bug.
Hopefully this solves the issue.

Comment: Actually i'd parked this for now. Thanks so much I'll test out today!