# Assets API doesn't return metadata in registerUpload

Tags: linkedin-api

When I make the first POST to the `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload` endpoint, the response I get back is missing the contents of the `metadata` field (example below):

```
{
  "value": {
    "mediaArtifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFo8azpCiJbBQ,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:uploadedVideo)",
    "uploadMechanism": {
      "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MultipartUpload": {
        "partUploadRequests": [
          {
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
            },
            "byteRange": {
              "lastByte": 4194303,
              "firstByte": 0
            },
            "url": ...,
            "urlExpiresAt": 1646512346348
          },
          ...
        ],
        "metadata": ""
      }
    },
    "asset": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFo8azpCiJbBQ",
    "assetRealTimeTopic": "urn:li-realtime:digitalmediaAssetUpdatesTopic:urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFo8azpCiJbBQ"
  }
}
```

...which prevents the later `completeMultiPartUpload` call from succeeding, since the `metadata` is a required field there (simply excluding the `metadata` field in the call doesn't work, and the field is required according to a previous question: [LinkedIn Marketing API- Invalid complete multipartUpload request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302769/linkedin-marketing-api-invalid-complete-multipartupload-request))

Is this a known problem with the API? Or am I missing something earlier that prevents the metadata from being returned?

Comment: Did you ever find out why this is happening? I'm getting the same response where the metadata is empty.

Comment: So while I'm not working on that particular project anymore and can't test it, from looking back at the git history I _think_ the problem was that uploads less than 200MB can't be uploaded as multiparts, and need to be uploaded all at once.